# Getting retval, cleanup, destroy failed using Papi

Tags: c, papi

I am trying to test out using papi, but I am getting some errors that I don't understand why they're occurring. I couldn't find anything online for them. The code is below

I am using [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) and C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "papi.h"

#define INDEX 100

static void test_fail(char *file, int line, char *call, int retval);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    extern void dummy(void *);
    float matrixa[INDEX][INDEX], matrixb[INDEX][INDEX], mresult[INDEX]    [INDEX];
    float real_time, proc_time, mflops;
    long long flpins;
    int retval, status = 0;
    int i,j,k;
    long_long values[1];

    FILE *file; 
    file = fopen("output.txt","w"); 

    retval = PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT);
    int EventSet = PAPI_NULL;
    PAPI_create_eventset(&EventSet);
    if(PAPI_add_event(EventSet, PAPI_LD_INS) != PAPI_OK)
    {
        fprintf(file,"PAPI failed to add Load/Store instructions\n");
    }

    if (PAPI_state(EventSet, &status) != PAPI_OK)
        fprintf(file,"state fail\n");

    fprintf(file, "State is now %d\n", status);
    if (PAPI_start(EventSet) != PAPI_OK)
        fprintf(file,"start fail\n");

    if (PAPI_state(EventSet, &status) != PAPI_OK)
        fprintf(file,"state2 fail\n");

    fprintf(file, "State is now %d\n", status);

    /* Initialize the Matrix arrays */
    for ( i=0; i<INDEX; i++ ){
        mresult[0][i] = 0.0;
        matrixa[0][i] = matrixb[0][i] = rand()*(float)1.1; }

    if((retval=PAPI_flops( &real_time, &proc_time, &flpins, &mflops))<PAPI_OK)
        fprintf(file,"retval failed\n");

    for (i=0;i<INDEX;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<INDEX;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<INDEX;k++)
            {
                mresult[i][j]=mresult[i][j] + matrixa[i][k]*matrixb[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    if((retval=PAPI_flops( &real_time, &proc_time, &flpins, &mflops))        <PAPI_OK)
    {
        fprintf(infile,"ret2 failed\n");
    }

    fprintf(file,"Real_time:\t%f\nProc_time:\t%f\nTotal flpins:\t%lld \nMFLOPS:\t\t%f\n",
            real_time, proc_time, flpins, mflops); 
    fflush(file);
    fprintf(file,"%s\tPASSED\n", __FILE__);
    fflush(file);

    if (PAPI_read(EventSet, values) != PAPI_OK)
      {fprintf(file,"read fail\n");}

      if (PAPI_stop(EventSet, values) != PAPI_OK)
      {fprintf(file,"stop fail\n");}

    if (PAPI_cleanup_eventset(&EventSet) != PAPI_OK)
      {fprintf(file,"cleanup fail\n");}

    if (PAPI_destroy_eventset(&EventSet) != PAPI_OK)
      {fprintf(file,"destroy fail\n");}


      fprintf(file,"\nValues is %f\n", values[0]);
      fflush(file);
      fclose(file);

      PAPI_shutdown();
      exit(0);
    }
```

In the output file, I just see the below:

```
    State is now 1
    State is now 2
    retval failed
    ret2 failed
    Real_time:      0.000000
    Proc_time:      0.000000
    Total flpins:   99
    MFLOPS:         0.000000
    PAPI_flops.c    PASSED
    cleanup fail
    destroy fail
```

I don't understand why ret, ret2, cleanup and destroy failed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PAPI_perror` or `PAPI_strerror` functions to get the error message associated with an error return value. This may help track down why, for example, `PAPI_flops` is failing. (It could be that there is no support on your system for the required events.)

The reason why `PAPI_cleanup_eventset` is failing though is because it takes just the integer `EventSet`, not a pointer to it.

I'd strongly recommend emitting the error return value strings, and also compiling with warnings on — the latter would likely have found the issue with the wrong parameter type.

Comment: I used the `test_fail` and got the output `Error in retval: EventSet is currently counting` after the line `retval=PAPI_flops( &real_time, &proc_time, &flpins, &mflops))<PAPI_OK`

Comment: `PAPI_flops` wants to be the one that starts the counters it is interested in, according to the man page. It might not be possible to use this high level routine simultaneously with using explicit event sets.